# What is the use of indexes in Couchbase server?

Tags: couchbase

Can anyone explain what is the use of indexes in Couchbase server in layman terms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indexes in Couchbase Server are used for the same reason indexes are used in any database: to enable and enhance the performance of queries.